# My storyboard custom class property doesn't generate a custom class in Xamarin anymore?

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac and design my UI in a storyboard using Xcode interface builder.

I'm trying to create a custom class of a UILabel and usually I just select the control and add my custom class name in the class property in xcode, and when xcode synchronises with Xamarin, the custom class is generated as a new file in the xamarin project, but this has stopped working.

Actually is seems to have stopped syncing all together. Are there any logs that I can check to see why? I have restarted xcode. Visual Studio for Mac, cleaned the project, deleted the bin and obj folders from the active project and rebooted the machine without success.

Any tips is very much appreciated!

Comment: I just test in the VS-Mac(8.4 Preview) and XCode 11,  the custom class is generated as a new file in the xamarin project as you described in the question. Can you try create a new project and do the same thing to see if it works? Or Update VS?

Comment: Thanks for testing! I can confirm that it's the same behaviour if I create a new clean project with the standard ios template. I've also noticed that the XCode UI has started to open in "two windows", where it used to open in just one? I'd don't know what the windows are called but basically it's one with the storyboard UI and the "Scene navigator" and one with the "Project Navigator". Related?

Comment: I also get two windows when I choose open the storyboard with XCode Interface Builder. I modify the the storyboard in the "Project Navigator" as you mentioned above. After finishing design the storyboard, I close the XCode and save the files. Then come back to the VS-Mac, I can see the custom classes.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a workaround and not a true answer as this has never worked for me. I have always used Xamarin iOS Designer to create custom class, then after file generation, close xib/storyboard and reopen in Xcode Interface Builder. Double checking for [Register("ClassName"]` tag.

**Select Label in iOS Designer:**
[image: Select Label in iOS Designer]

**View -> Pads -> Properties Add Class name in Class Field:**
[image: Custom class entry]

**Should see custom class autogenerated in SolutionExplorer:**
[image]

**Ensure .designer.cs file has Register Tag:**
[image]

Now you can close the .xib in VS for Mac and reopen in Xcode. It probably won't autocomplete. But any Outlets you create will be an instance of your custom class as well as any custom attributes specified in .cs files will apply at runtime. Not as convenient as creating the custom class with Xcode but at least now you can use your custom class with Xcode Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That actually works but it has been working fine from XCode which is where I'm more confident working so i'd really like to find out why it doesn't anymore?!

Comment: Will definitely keep following in case someone does answer I'd never seen this work before in my 2 or so years of Xamarin.iOS but would certainly like to!

Answer (score 1):

I love my XCode as well! Instead of doing what you used to do, you can

1. Open the file in Xcode interface builder as usual with the Label
2. Find and Open the `ABCViewController.h` file in the other XCode window.
3. Hold `control` on your keyboard, click on your label on the GUI and drag it to the `ABCViewController.h` file and it should prompt you to create an outlet and name the class.
4. Save and Quit, and you should see the new Properties in your `ABCViewController.designer.cs` file

There's definitely a new issue after the update as you can see [here as well](https://www.reddit.com/r/xamarindevelopers/comments/esxf2c/open_in_xcode_interface_builder_not_working_with/)